# JUnit Theory for all tests - only parameterized setup method needed

Tags: unit-testing, testing, parameters, junit, theory

I've got some tests in one class that all depend on variables set in the setup method. Therefore it would be good if I could run all tests multiple times with different global variables.

I know you can use `Theory` for a single test, but I would like to use it for all tests. My first approach resulted in the error that the setup method can't have any arguments.

I there for workaround for this? I don't want to annotate every single test in the class and add some configuration logic, if this can be handled in a central setup method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Parameterized](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html)?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 },
                 { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 } });
    }

    private int fInput;
    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```

> Each instance of FibonacciTest will be constructed using the two-argument constructor and the data values in the @Parameters method.

Comment: Yeah found that last night, thanks :-) I though Theories are the new way to go, but they don't quite cover it.